# Angular 1.x clone service

Tags: angularjs, service, clone

For example i have `service` like this:

```
services.User=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.obj = {
        _id: "",
        fullname: "",
        email: "",
    }
    self.save = function(user){
        self.obj._id=user._id;
        self.obj.fullname=user.fullname;
        self.obj.email=user.email;
    }
}
```

and i need `service` or `factory` which will extend this. I have tried this:

```
factories.MyUser=function(User){
    User.save({
        _id: '123',
        fullname: 'Honchar Denys',
        email: 'crackeraki@gmail.com'
    });
    return User;
}
```

This didn't extend it, but use it and if i call something like this:

```
factories.MyPartner=function(User){
    User.save({
        _id: '234',
        fullname: 'Honchar Maria',
        email: 'margood1990@gmail.com'
    });
    return User;
}
```

One of two factories will rewrite other. `Service.User` is called only once, how can i make it duplicate for each time something call it. The end result is that `MyUser` and `MyPartner` injection in controllers have the same `.obj` object. Is there a way to `angular.copy(factoryInstance)`?

Comment: i don't understand your problem. Do you want to have a single factory returning 2 functions?

Comment: I need service with many functions which will be cloned and not used.

Comment: My problem is that when i add object with data into the service, i can't use that data in two different places. I have modified the question so it be more clear.

Comment: First problem is you aren't returning `$http` promises. Otherwise it is very hard to understand what you are asking

Comment: i have save function in two places, both of them replacing object in one place. I need clone of service User, can't understand why that is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a help of @georgeawg i came up to below:

```
service.User=function(){
    this.save = function(user,newUser){
        user._id=newUser._id;
        user.fullName=newUser.fullName;
        user.email=newUser.email;
    }
}
```

this is service which will host all functions is needed for shema User. Then we have those factories:

```
documents.MyUser=function(User){
    var user = angular.copy(User);
    user.obj={
        _id: "123",
        fullname: "Honchar Denys",
        email: "crackeraki@gmail.com",
    };
    return user;
}
documents.MyPartner=function(User){
    var user = angular.copy(User);
    user.obj={
        _id: "234",
        fullname: "Honchar Maria",
        email: "margood1990@gmail.com",
    };
    return user;
}
```

which return different User.obj.

Answer (score 1):

### Creating Multiple Instances from an AngularJS Factory

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.factory("MyPartner", function($http){
    function newPartner () {
        var myParter = {};
        var promise = $http.get('/api/user/myPartner');

        myPartner.$promise = promise
          .then ( function onFulfilled(response) {
            angular.merge(myPartner, response.data);
            return myPartner;
        });
        return myPartner;
    };
    return newPartner; 
});
```

It is important to realize that invoking the `MyPartner.newPartner` function immediately returns an empty reference. Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

The `MyPartner` object has this additional property:

- `$promise`: the [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) of the original server interaction that created this instance.

On success, the [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is resolved with the same resource instance or collection object, updated with data from server. This makes it easy to use in [resolve section of $routeProvider.when()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) to defer view rendering until the resource is loaded.

On failure, the promise is rejected with the [http response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) object.

Comment: I have tried this, first i believe you have an error , it should be `return newPartner()`, next if you put `console.log("Hello")` inside function `newPartner` you will see that function only once, no matter where you inject factory `MyPartner`.

Comment: I will remove http from my question, this is not the issue.

Comment: It should be `return newPartner` to return the function *reference*. The function is then invoked with `MyPartner.newPartner()`. Invoked **outside** the factory.

Comment: can you check my examples, how i have one instance and injecting in others, instance it self called once and values are saved into that instance.  Can you modify my service instance so the others will work?

Answer (score 1):

```
services.User=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.save = function(user){
        var obj = {};
        obj._id=user._id;
        obj.fullname=user.fullname;
        obj.email=user.email;
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: i see your logic, it's a bit different from mine in my examples. I will check if that could be comfortable. Basically what i am trying to success is that have service or factory for each my database schema. And after that have  service or factory which will user them.